# I have a Picker which contains data and label as props.but when i open the picker label or place holder is also showing in data, but i want only data

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, npm, react-native-picker-select

[image: app screenshot]

```
         <Picker
          label={strings('Uploaddocs.Identity_Type')}
          width={metrics.width - metrics.getW(40)}
          value={this.state.idType}
          data = {identityType}
          valueExtractor={(item) => item.value}
          labelExtractor={(item) => item.value}
          onChange={(value, index, item) => {
            this.setState({ idType: value})
          }}
        />
```

above label is = 'identity type'
data is = [{value:passport, value:driving licence , value:id card}]

and i want only data in drop down.

Comment: Guys please help me i'm freshie in react-native .
Please look into this matter!

Comment: I think you have tagged the wrong library, are you using [this](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown)?

Comment: I'm using the react-native-picker-select.

Comment: [react-native-picker-select](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select) has no props called labelExtractor, valueExtractor or label. Is this the right library?

Comment: Try using placeholder